# Почему ajax не отправляет данные? Как собрать данные input, находящиеся в div'е?

Tags: ajax, serialize, form, javascript

Приветствую.

Сделал скрипт сбора данных из imput по типу

```
data: "id_staff=" + jQuery('#id_staff').val() + "&name=" + jQuery('#name').val() +"и т.д.,
```

Если, допустим, я оставляю поле пустым, почему-то запрос не выполняется! Почему?

Еще вопрос:

Как собрать данные из всех input и подготовить к отправке, не заключая все в form? Сейчас у меня все input находятся в div.

Что-то похожее на

```
  var form_data = $('form').serialize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = {};
$('form').each(function () {
  var name = $('input',this).attr('name');
  data[name] = $('input',this).val();
});
// и дальше просто в ajax передаете
$.ajax({
...
data:data,
...
})
```